# I do not know how to write the equations how can ı do?

Tags: equations, subequations

How can ı write this equation? Thank you for helping.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us the TeX code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation in your screenshot requires not only the `cases` (or `dcases`) environment and the macros `mathbb` ("blackboard bold math"), `\mathcal` (for `\mathcal{N}` and `\mathcal{H}`), and `\bm` (for bold-italic `y`), but also -- somewhat unusually, I'd say -- the use of `\mathrm` for the `x` and `w` subscript terms. Finally, some variant of a Times Roman type math font appears to be in use.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,bm}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbb{T}_i(\bm{y}_i)=
\begin{dcases}
\mathcal{N}(N\sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^2, 
    2N\sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^4), 
    & \mathcal{H}_0 \\
\mathcal{N}(N(\sigma_{\mathrm{x}}^2+\sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^2), 
    2N(\sigma_{\mathrm{x}}^2+\sigma_{\mathrm{w}}^2)^2),
    & \mathcal{H}_1
\end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Based on the font of the black board bold `T` I'm guessing the font is `stix` or similar to it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stix}  % Just a guess at the font based on the black board bold
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \mathbb{T}_i(\bm{y}_i) \sim 
        \begin{cases}
            \mathcal{N}(N\sigma_w^2, 2N\sigma_w^4), & \mathcal{H}_0\\
            \mathcal{N}(N(\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_w^2), 2N(\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_w^2)^2), & \mathcal{H}_1
        \end{cases}
    \]
\end{document}
```